# Active_admin: ArgumentError in Admin/events#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I've just installed active_admin and created the first resource - videos - perfectly find.  Everything worked like a charm.

But now that I'm trying to add 'users' and 'events' it is failing with the same message when I navigate to them in the menu.

Here is what it says:

```
   ArgumentError in Admin/events#index

    Showing /Users/markwalker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

    wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)
    Extracted source (around line #1):

    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
    Rails.root: /Users/markwalker/Xavy2

    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
    app/helpers/application_helper.rb:3:in `select_tag'
    Request

`Parameters`:

    {"order"=>"id_desc"}
```

Has anyone experience this before, or have an idea about what might be causing it?

Let me know if I need to add more code to make sense of the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 0):

Couple observations, jfdimark

Shouldn't `{"order"=>"id_desc"}` be `{"order"=>"id desc"}` (no underscore)?

Apart from that, it's hard to diagnose without seeing the Full Trace.  A similar problem with `ArgumentError in Admin/dashboard#index` brought me to your question in the first place, but simply looking at my Full Trace I saw:

`RedCloth (4.2.9) lib/redcloth/erb_extension.rb:16:in`textilize'`

as the first line. I actually wasn't using RedCloth in this project, so I took it out of my Gemfile and all's good.

Comment: Hi Eric, this doesn't resolve the problem I have above.  However if anyone else comes to the question with the issue you had, you can solve it like this:[https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1805]